# How to inject mock into @Autowired field in an abstract parent class with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, superclass

I'm writing a Unit test for a class that has an abstract superclass, and one of the functions in the ChildClass is calling a method on an object form the BaseClass.

`ChildClass` looks something like this.

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public void functionA(){
        objectFromParentClass.functionB();
    }
}
```

The parent class

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    @Autowired
    protected typeFromParentClass objectFromParentClass;

    public void someFunction() {}
}
```

Since a parent class is abstract `@InjectMocks` and <s>ReflectionTestUtils()</s> doesn't work. Is there any way to inject a mocked `objectFromParentClass` into the `ParentClass` with Mockito?

Edit: Neither the Child nor the Parent class was written by me, i'm just testing it.

Comment: create a getter/setterin the parent class and in your test class add annotations Spy (to make getter return a mock) + InjectMocks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReflectionTestUtils.setField()` does work in this case

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

Here's a Junit5 extension we wrote to solve this exact problem. Essentially it takes a map of objects and injects them into the fields of the class under test. Perfect for where InjectMocks falls short!